# <SwiperSlide> is not getting created inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying to dynamically create a SwiperSlide tag inside a map function. The docs in Swiper JS are hard coded but I would like them to be dynamically.

The replicable code is here - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-react-effect-coverflow-forked-67pckv?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A21%2C30

in Line 35 even if I try to specify the SwipeSlide inside the map using JSX syntax it's not reflecting anything in the output. Need help in this.

```
{items.map((item) => {
    <SwiperSlide>{item}</SwiperSlide>
})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the **SwiperSlide** from **map** function, please update as following:

```
{items.map((item) => {
   return(
     <SwiperSlide>{item}</SwiperSlide>
   )
})}
```

Or you can do this as well:

```
{items.map((item) => (
     <SwiperSlide>{item}</SwiperSlide>
))}
```

Comment: Hi @Hamza Khursheed Thanks a lot. It's working.

Comment: Just curious, Could you tell me what's the difference between the code in question and the code in your second suggestion? it's the same right ?

Comment: The difference is, you have used curly braces "{" and I used parenthesis "(". Parenthesis behave as return statement here.